# Typescript's custom Promise class doesn't work

Tags: javascript, typescript, class, ecmascript-6, promise

I tried to create a custom class which extends builtin `Promise`, but some of it's method doesn't works as expected.

The following es6 will work:

```
class MyPromise extends Promise{
    mythen(cb){
        return this.then(cb)
    }
}
MyPromise.resolve().mythen(()=>1).mythen(console.log)
```

But the following typescipt doesn't:

```
class MyPromise<T> extends Promise<T>{
    mythen(cb){
        return this.then(cb)
    }
}
MyPromise.resolve().mythen(()=>1).mythen(console.log)
```

I found that `MyPromise.resolve()` returns `Promise<void>` instead of `MyPromise<void>`.
However, according to es6's behavior, `MyPromise.resolve()` does returns `MyPromise<void>`.

Does it means I have to override every `Promise` method such as `resolve` `then` `catch` ....?

Comment: Have you considered actually adding types? Your typescript example is missing a return type for example.

Comment: @Evert I know that I could add those types by myself, but es6's behavior means `MyPromise.resolve()` does return `MyPromise<void>` instead of `Promise<void>`. However, typescript cannot correctly handle it.

Comment: I missed that the problem happened with `resolve()`, not `then()`. Ignore my comment. Not sure if Typescript is capable of returning 'instance of static self'.

Comment: you might have to override `resolve()`

Comment: @DanielA.White Does it means I have to override every static and instance method on Promise in order to make it work? It seems like that every custom Promise returns custom Promise instance...

Comment: TypeScript does not currently support [higher kinded types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/1213); specifically, there is no support for any sort of [parametric polymorphic `this`](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5845), which is what you'd need to express that an extension of `Promise<T>` should return a `this<T>`.  You'll have to override everything you care about, unfortunately.